# Flutter Go Router Deep Linking Not Working As Expected

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router, flutter-deep-link

I am trying to add an action extension to my Flutter app. I intend to use action to send an image to my app. Go Router was used for routing in my app, so I have to use Go Router for deep links.
Due to the complexity of my app, I need to navigate to a nested route.

Everything looks as it should be but I face some unexpected behaviours.
Either Action extension or `xcrun simctl openurl booted <url>` command opens the app but not navigating the correct path. Also `redirect` not invoking while opening from extension or command prompt.

Here is my route config

```dart
final _router = GoRouter(
  redirect: (context, state) {
    print(state);
    return null;
  },
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => const MyHomePage(),
    ),
    GoRoute(path: '/first', builder: (context, state) => const FirstScreen(), routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: 'image-capture',
        builder: (context, state) => const ImageDart(),
      ),
    ]),
  ],
);
```

Here is the custom url scheme part from info.plist

```xml
 <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.bahadirarslan.goRouterDeeplink</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>gorouterapp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

I tried the commands below to invoke routing

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted gorouterapp://com.bahadirarslan.goRouterDeeplink/first
xcrun simctl openurl booted gorouterapp://com.bahadirarslan.goRouterDeeplink/first/image
xcrun simctl openurl booted gorouterapp://first/image       
xcrun simctl openurl booted gorouterapp://a/first/image
xcrun simctl openurl booted gorouterapp:/first/image
```

Neither of the commands above opened any route except the home screen.

Also, I am aware of [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100624) record but the issue was closed as done but I still couldn't figure out the change or effect of this work.

To simplify, I created an example app that behaves as described above. I hope you can show me, my mistake.

https://github.com/bahadirarslan/go_router_deeplink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a setting from `info.plist` to enable Flutter Deep Linking. Add these to your `info.plist`:

```
<key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

Also, the path for the image capture is not `image` as in your example, but `image-capture`. After the above change, these do work:

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted gorouterapp://com.bahadirarslan.goRouterDeeplink/first
xcrun simctl openurl booted gorouterapp://com.bahadirarslan.goRouterDeeplink/first/image-capture
```

Comment: You are right. This explains why it is not working at all. I will add then probably update the question because my actual problem was a little bit different. Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes it worked now I can not recreate my original problem :) May be I will ask another question. What a silly mistake btw :D

Comment: In my real-life app my deeplink works only once and then go_router stop responding deeplinks. Do you have any idea about that, it is too much complicated to create a simple example.

Comment: Without details, it is hard to tell. Do you get any debug info? Does it happen on real device as well, or only in simulator?

Comment: Surprisingly I noticed that the internet_connection_checker package causing very strange behaviour. If I use the hasConnection method, go_router is affecting.

Comment: Well, that package was updated like 1.5 yrs ago. I would not recommend using it, tons of things changed since then.